# Localhost/172.. connection timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am new to MERN and following the following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqJlxBYj-M When I try to access localhost the connection times out even though the back end is running (server running on port 5000) as well as the front end (when I run npm run start it starts up and says I can run the project on http://localhost:3000 or http://172.17.0.12:3000)

This is the app.js file

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the server code for the backend:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require ('cors');
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    require('dotenv').config();

    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.use(cors());
   app.use(express.json());

    const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
    mongoose.connect(uri, {});
    const connection = mongoose.connection;
    connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established   successfully')
    });

const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port: '+port);
});
```

Comment: If you are running it on the port 5000, you should try to open the server on http://localhost:5000 instead of 3000

Comment: share us the code or at least the package.json

Comment: I have shared the code for the backend file that I run node on and the app.js file which is supposed to show When I run localhost:3000.

Comment: Also running it on port 5000 also times out